# Proof of $f(x)\in I\Leftrightarrow f(i)=0\Leftrightarrow f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1) (q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x])$.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I am reading "Introduction to Algebra" (in Japanese) by Makoto Ishida.

The following example is in this book:

> Example 2:
> Let $g$ be a mapping from $\mathbb{R}[x]$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{R}[x]\ni f(x)\mapsto f(i)\in\mathbb{C}$.
> Then, $g$ is a surjective ring homomorphism.
> Let $I:=\ker g$.
> $f(x)\in I\Leftrightarrow f(i)=0\Leftrightarrow f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1) (q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x])$.
> So, $I=(x^2+1)$.
> By the First Ring Isomorphism Theorem, $$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\mathbb{C}.$$

I understand the following fact holds:
$f(x)\in I\Leftrightarrow f(i)=0\Leftrightarrow f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1) (q(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x])$.

Then, I proved that $q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ as follows:

> Assume that $q(x)=a_nx^n+\dots +a_1x+a_0\in\mathbb{C}[x]-\mathbb{R}[x]$.
> Then, $a_j\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ for some $j\in\{0,\dots,n\}$.
> $\mathbb{R}[x]\ni f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)=a_nx^{n+2}+a_{n-1}x^{n+1}+(a_{n-2}+a_n)x^n+(a_{n-3}+a_{n-1})x^{n-1}+\dots+(a_0+a_2)x^2+a_1x+a_0.$
> Let $k:=\min\{j\mid a_j\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}\}$.
> Since $a_k\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ and $a_k+a_{k+2}\in\mathbb{R}$, $a_{k+2}\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ must hold.
> Since $a_{k+2}\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ and $a_{k+2}+a_{k+4}\in\mathbb{R}$, $a_{k+4}\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ must hold.
> $\cdots$
> So, $a_{n-1}\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ or $a_n\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ must hold.
> But $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a_{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}$.
> This is a contradiction.

I am not sure my proof is ok or not.
If my proof is not ok, then please tell me a proof.
If my proof is ok, then please tell me a standard proof of the above fact.

Comment: Trivial comment. It would be better not to use $i$ as an index.

Comment: I think the easiest proof is to use the fact that $f(i)=0$ iff $\bar{f(i)}=0$ iff $f(-i)=0$ and so $f$ has a factor $(x-i)(x+i)$

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you very much for your advice and comment. I edited and changed from $i$ to $j$ as an index.

Comment: Usually the proof is "by the division algorithm".  That is, the quotient of the division algorithm lies in the same polynomial ring over a field as that of the divisor and dividend polynomials.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: By the division algorithm, $f(x)=q_2(x)(x^2+1)+ax+b$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. $0=f(i)=ai+b$. So, $a=b=0$. So, $f(x)=q_2(x)(x^2+1)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. We can think $f(x)=q_2(x)(x^2+1)$ as an equation in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. On the other hand, $f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. By uniqueness of division theorem for polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, $q(x)=q_2(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$.